# The Android.mk and the bp file exist in the same directory

Tags: android, makefile, build, android-soong

The mk file and the bp file exist in the same directory.
Which one will take effect?

Which one will take effect?
I want to konw which I should modify.
I checked the Android official website, but I didn't find a clear answer.